# Flatten a multdimensional Tree array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a Tree structured array with parent child relations.
I want the array to be flattened for easy parsing.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ParentID] => 11653
        [FolderID] => 11823
        [Items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ParentID] => 11823
                        [FolderID] => 11824
                        [Items] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ParentID] => 11824
                                        [FolderID] => 11827
                                        [Items] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [ParentID] => 11827
                                                        [FolderID] => 11828
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ParentID] => 11823
                        [FolderID] => 11825
                        [Items] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ParentID] => 11825
                                        [FolderID] => 11826
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Desired output :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ParentID] => 11653
        [FolderID] => 11823
 )
[1] => Array
      (
    [ParentID] => 11823
    [FolderID] => 11824
   )
[2] => Array
        (
    [ParentID] => 11824
    [FolderID] => 11827
    )
[3] => Array
        (
    [ParentID] => 11827
    [FolderID] => 11828
    )
[4] => Array
        (
    [ParentID] => 11823
    [FolderID] => 11825
    )
[5] => Array
(
    [ParentID] => 11825
    [FolderID] => 11826
)

)
```

I Have tried many flattening logic found in here, but i couldn't get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) where $array is your array and $new_array is the flattened array.

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) use (&$new_array, &$i)
{
    $new_array[(int) $i][$key] = $item; 
    ($key == 'ParentID') ?: $i++;
});

var_dump($new_array);
```

If you want it for parsing you could also just do:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key)
{
    *Your parsing for each array*
});
```

Comment: Getting Error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot unset string offsets

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not getting that error on my system. How about now? I've removed some unnecessary stuff such as the unset.

Answer (score 1):

This function works well for flattening multi-dimensional arrays:

```
function array_flatten($array)
{ 
    if(!is_array($array)) { 
        return FALSE; 
    } 

    $result = array(); 

    foreach($array as $key => $value) { 
        if(is_array($value)) { 
            $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
        } else { 
          $result[$key] = $value; 
        } 
    }

    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it returns only the last pair
    Array
    (
    [ParentID] => 11825
    [FolderID] => 11826
    )

Answer (score -1):

Start with a static variable.

Then create a function which accepts an array, iterates over it, and adds an element to your static variable with the ParentID and FolderID.  If the array also contains an element with name "Items" and is an array, then apply it recursively to this function.