# How to get list all multidimensional array with parent index

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

How to get list all multidimensional array with parent index. All index in each level is unique and i want to show all list with the level.

example my arrays:

```
 Array(
[1] => Array(
        [2] => Array(
                [3] => 
                [4] => 
                [7] => 
            )
    )

[6] => Array(
        [11] => Array(
                [12] =>  Array(
                         [17] => 
                        )
            )
    )

[2] => Array(
        [13] => Array(
                [14] => 
            )

    )
 )
```

I want to get output like this:

```
Array
(
 [1]=array([level] = 1)
 [2]=array([level] = 2)
 [3]=array([level] = 3)
 [4]=array([level] = 3)
 [7]=array([level] = 3)
 [6]=array([level] = 1)
 [11]=array([level] = 2)
 [12]=array([level] = 3)
 [17]=array([level] = 4)
 ...
 )
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516892/flatten-a-multdimensional-tree-array-in-php

Comment: @cobolt i tried but not work, because i need to get the level too.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur, what is the benefit of such output structure `[1]=array([level] = 1)` ? It's obvious that one item may occupy only one level, what is nested array `['level' => ...]` for? I've got a working solution and I suggest to output either in string manner like `value: 1, level: 1,` OR in 2d array like `['value'=>1, 'level' => 1], ['value'=>3, 'level' => 3]`

Comment: Impossible in this example. `array[2]` (level 1) will overwrite `array[1][2]` (level 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `recursive` function. Assuming your `array` will have a `NULL` value if there is no more child/nested arrays.

```
$arr = array(1 => array(2 => array(3 => NULL, 
                                       4 => NULL,
                                       7 => NULL )),
             6 => array(11 => array(12 =>  array(17 =>NULL))),
             2 => array(13 => array(14 => NULL)));

$rslt_arr = array();

function traverse_arr($array, $level)
{
    $level++;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if($value != NULL){
            traverse_arr($value, $level);
        }
        $GLOBALS['rslt_arr'][$key]['level'] = $level;
    }
}

traverse_arr($arr, 0);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rslt_arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [level] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [level] => 3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [level] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [level] => 4
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [level] => 3
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [level] => 1
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [level] => 3
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [level] => 2
        )

)
```